# Sql Select 0 1 0 1 sequence from database table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

I need to fetch output from given below table in 
0 
1
0
1 
sequence .All other data at the end of table.

```
create table #Temp
(
    EventID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key ,
    Value bit
)
INSERT  INTO  #Temp(Value) Values
(0),(1)
,(0),(0)
,(0),(0)
,(0),(0)
,(1),(1)
,(1),(1)
,(1),(0)
,(0),(0)
,(1),(1)
,(0),(1)
```

Comment: can u show a sample of the output you want @Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
select *
from #Temp
order by row_number() over (partition by Value order by EventID), Value
```

Comment: **Thanks** @dnoeth . This is what exactly i needed.